# RabbitMQ fail connection

Tags: java, spring, exception, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I need help, my app (client) connect to RabbitMQ server and when server shutdown, my app cannot start....

Listener can't created and app failed start.
Or when virtual host dont have queue my app cant start too

So my question

**1) How to process exception in my config (all exception, i need was my app start if RabbitMQ server have problems)**

**2) What in my config look bad and need refactor**

i use

- Spring 4.2.9.RELEASE
- org.springframework.amqp 2.0.5.RELEASE
- Java 8

My 2 classes

1) Config for Beans RabbitMq

2) Listener annotation

```
    @EnableRabbit
    @Configuration
    public class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory factoryRabbit = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory();
        factoryRabbit.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(10000);
        factoryRabbit.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);

        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory(factoryRabbit);

        connectionFactory.setHost("DRIVER_APP_IP");
        connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
        connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(10);
        connectionFactory.setUsername("user");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("pass");
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/vhost");

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        try {
            RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
            rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(this.DRIVER_QUEUE);
            rabbitTemplate.setQueue(this.DRIVER_QUEUE);
            return rabbitTemplate;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            return new RabbitTemplate();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(this.DRIVER_QUEUE);
    }


    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
        return factory;
    }
    }

    @Component
    public class RabbitMqListener {

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = DRIVER_QUEUE, durable = "true"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = "exchange", ignoreDeclarationExceptions = "true", autoDelete = "true"))
    )
    public String balancer(byte[] message) throws InterruptedException {
        String json = null;
        try {
             "something move"
        } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    }
```

Comment: Try do not use `factoryRabbit.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true)`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#auto-recovery

Comment: it's first bean in my config, it's don't help. I think it's for help reconnect if app work and rabbit shutdown, when rabbit start, you connect automatically

Comment: My problem now @RabbitListener. His have Exception when cannot creating bean, and system don't start

Comment: What is an exception, please. The `ignoreDeclarationExceptions = "true"` should do the trick, but you still have to use ` factoryRabbit.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);`

Comment: for example
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue '78768' in vhost '/vhost', class-id=50, method-id=10)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution my problem

**First** it's Bean container!
We need this

factory.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);

this property give our when queue lost on server RabbitMQ, our app don't crash and can start

```
@Bean

public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setStartConsumerMinInterval(3000L);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);

    factory.setRecoveryInterval(15000L);
    factory.setStartConsumerMinInterval(1000L);
    factory.setReceiveTimeout(10000L);
    factory.setChannelTransacted(true);
    return factory;
}
```

and **second**

```
@Component
    public class RabbitMqListener {

@RabbitListener(containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory", queues = DRIVER_QUEUE)
public String balancer(byte[] message) throws InterruptedException {
    String json = null;
    try {
         "something move"
    } catch (Exception ex) {
}
}
```

I set containerFactory and Queue in @RabbitListener and drop other propertys,
because i don't need it
I hope it's help somebody, thank all for you attention and sorry for my English